# change character_set_connection utf8mb4 mysql

Tags: mysql, aws, amazon-ec2

I want to change character_set_connection utf8mb4. Its showing me utf8. I have follow this https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4 article and changed

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
```

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Also fire this query.

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

but when I check current status in **phpmyadmin** using

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character_set_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
```

result

```
character_set_client utf8
character_set_connection utf8
character_set_database latin1
character_set_filesystem binary
character_set_results utf8
character_set_server latin1
character_set_system utf8
collation_connection utf8_general_ci
collation_database latin1_swedish_ci
collation_server latin1_swedish_ci
```

I have set alter tables and database

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4;  
ALTER DATABASE openfire CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;  
ALTER TABLE ofOffline CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

This is my connections string

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/openfire?rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useUnicode=true
```

MySQL  5.6.33 I have check in windows with version 5.7.14 it's fine. Please give me any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What client are you using?  You will need to specify that the connection is to be with utf8mb4.

What about the tables?  If you have existing tables, an `ALTER ... CONVERT TO` will be needed.

Answer (score 0):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) based on a comment originally left by the question author:</sub>*

Finally I solved this issue. The problem is in phpmyadmin: I can see those `character_set_client` using MySQL query in `putty` command but still not in phpmyadmin.

It's a bug in phpmyadmin as mentioned in [How to support full Unicode in MySQL databases](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4) by Mathias Bynens.